# Adding link in rotating javascript banner

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, href

I have a rotating banner that I need to add links to [example](http://www.advancedfluids.com/2012/). Below is part of the js code. My problem getting the href to work in the index.php page.

```
function change_banner(){

data=xmldata[changenum];                    //get current banner XML object 

img=$(data).attr("src");                    //retrieve variables
href=$(data).attr("href");
target=$(data).attr("target");

$(".banner_img_href").attr("href",href);        //change variables on HTML
$(".banner_img_href").attr("target",target);
$("#banner_image").attr("src",img);
```

This is the html:

```
<div class="banner">
    <div class="banner_text">
        <img src="images/banner_text.png">
    </div>
    <div class="banner_img">
         <img   border='0' src="images/banner_gas.png" id='banner_image' alt='Banner Image' />
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried basic linking but no dice. Not sure where I am going wrong with this.

Thank you,

B Graves

Comment: Are you wanting the whole banner clickable?

Comment: Where is `.banner_img_href` I can't see it in the source of the page. Your `$(".banner_img_href") ` returns an empty jQuery object

Comment: You said you tried basic link. Does that mean you tried wrapping your banner or parts of it in anchor tags?

Comment: I only need the machine images clickable. The javascript is calling an xml file which is calling the images I didn't create this so I am not sure exactly the thinking on it. And yes, I tried wrapping the image tags and I tried icluding the link with the images and putting it after the image, all with no results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you said you tried basic linking, but the following html *should* work:

```
<div class="banner">
    <div class="banner_text">
        <a class="banner_img_href" href="http://someurl.com">
            <img src="images/banner_text.png">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="banner_img">
         <a class="banner_img_href" href="http://someurl.com">
             <img border='0' src="images/banner_gas.png" id='banner_image' alt='Banner Image' />
         </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function change_banner(){

    data=xmldata[changenum];                    //get current banner XML object 

    img=$(data).attr("src");                    //retrieve variables
    href=$(data).attr("href");
    target=$(data).attr("target");

    $(".banner_img_href").attr("href",href);        //change variables on HTML
    $(".banner_img_href").attr("target",target);
    $("#banner_image").attr("src",img);
}
```

In your code, you didn't have any element with the class `banner_img_href`, so the href attribute wasn't actually being set on any element.

If this doesn't work, I would verify that your data actually contains a valid url for the href, and that you're able to retrieve it (use the developer tools in a browser to set a breakpoint and check the value, or output the value to the JavaScript console with `console.log(href)`).

EDIT: I just checked how you're getting the data and the format of the data.  Your XML file should probably formatted differently like this:

```
<gallery fade="500" ontime="5000">
    <picture src="images/banner_gas.png" href="desiccant-dryers-air-dryers.php" />
    <picture src="images/banner_liquid.png" href="backwashing-sand-filters.php" />
    <picture src="images/banner_mis.png" href="air-cooled-chillers-explosion-preventers.php" />
</gallery>
```

The problem is with the way you are getting the data, and the format of the data.  If you format the xml file as above, it should work fine.

Comment: The awesomeness of this group has yet to fail me. Thank you very much for your ingenuity and for your help.